# Why is !(~true) not true?

Tags: javascript, boolean-logic

In javascript the tilde operator is a bitwise NOT or complement, so why does the following not work as expected?

```
var x = true;
var tildeX = ~x;
var exclX = !x;


tildeX == exclX; // returns false
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is because `true` is equivalent to `1`, and when you perform a bitwise NOT (`~`) on the number `1` you get `-2`. Which when combined with the NOT operator (`!`) will produce false (because the only number that will produce true when combined with the NOT operator is `0`)

[Here is some information that you might find interesting](http://www.javascriptturnsmeon.com/the-tilde-operator-in-javascript/)

Quoted from the link:

> Bitwise NOTing any number x yields -(x + 1)

Answer (score 1):

~ is a bitwise operation:

~(true) = ~1 = 0b11111110 (with 8bit character)

! is boolean negation:

!(true) = !1 = 0b00000000

Answer (score 0):

`x` is not a boolean type and therefore has a load of leading bits set to zero.

`~x` will convert all those leading bits to `1`. Therefore it will be non-zero.

`!x`, on the other hand, is zero.

That's why `tildeX == exclX` compares false.